# Kotlin / JacksonXML - Deserialize XML occasional property (from Qt TS files)

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have the following XML structure (based on Qt TS file format) to de-serialize:

```
<context>
    <name>General</name>
    <message>
        <source>One</source>
        <translation>One</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Two</source>
        <translation>Two</translation>
    </message>
    <message numerus="yes">
        <source>Thing</source>
        <translation>
            <numerusform>Thing</numerusform>
            <numerusform>Things</numerusform>
        </translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

The Kotlin code to parse this:

```
data class Context(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
                   val name: String = "",
                   private val mMap: MutableList<Message> = mutableListOf()) {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "message")
    var messages = mMap
        set(value) {
            field.addAll(value); return
        }
}

data class Message(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "numerus", isAttribute = true)
                   val numerus: String? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "source")
                   val source: String? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "comment")
                   val comment: String? = null,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "translation")
                   val translation: Translation? = null)

data class Translation(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true)
                       val type: String? = null,
                       @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerText")
                       @JacksonXmlText
                       val text: String? = null,
                       private val numerusMap: MutableList<NumerusForm> = mutableListOf()) {
    // custom setter because otherwise the list isn't assembled correctly
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "numerusform")
    var numerusForm = numerusMap
        set(value) {
            field.addAll(value); return
        }
}

data class NumerusForm(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerText")
                       @JacksonXmlText
                       val text: String? = null
)
```

This code works if there are only

```
<translation 
   <numerusform>Thing</numerusform>
</translation>
```

properties available in the XML. As soon as I just have `<translation>One</translation>`, it crashes.

**Any idea on how to parse this property that is present just occasionally in the XML structure without crashing on the rest of the file ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by creating my own deserializer class from Jackson.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer

class MyOwnDeserizalizer : StdDeserializer<TSTransformerService.Translation>(Translation::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(jP: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Translation {

    //Gets the Translation element
    val rootNode: JsonNode = jP.getCodec().readTree<JsonNode>(jP)

    // Get and set the value from the rootnode

    return Translation(type, text, numerus)
 }
}
```

Some sources that helped:

- [jackson custom deserializer only getting last value in list xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831630/jackson-custom-deserializer-only-getting-last-value-in-list-xml)
- [Jackson Kotlin - Deserialize JsonNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279171/jackson-kotlin-deserialize-jsonnode)